# If principle $SU(N)$ bundles on 3-manifolds are trivial, how can there be magnetic monopoles?

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, topology, magnetic-monopoles, solitons

Magnetic monopoles are solitons, i.e. field configurations on space (which is 3 dimensional). In pure $SU(N)$ gauge theory, magnetic monopoles can be constructed via 't Hooft's abelian projection (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0010225).

However, there is also a result that states that principle $SU(N)$ bundles over 3-manifolds are trivial. Doesn't this contradict the existence of monopoles?

Edit: Maybe it has to do with the fact that the gauge group should be $SU(N)/\mathbb Z_N$ in which case there are non-trivial bundles?

Comment: What does the triviality of SU(N) bundles have to do with magnetic monopoles? The magnetic monopole is a non-trivial **U(1)**-bundle (since the U(1) is the electromagnetic gauge group). If you think your reference about 't Hooft monopoles states anywhere that the SU(N) configuration before SSB has to be a non-trivial SU(N) bundle, please be more explicit where you think it does so.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I don't think the abelian projection has much to do with SSB.

Comment: Why do you say so? Chapter 5.2 of your reference is explicitly about the different phases of such a projected theory under a Higgs-like mechanism (and "Higgs mechanism" is essentially just another word for SSB). In any case, whether this is essential to the notion of the Abelian projection is beside the point, I really just want to know where the statement about non-trivial SU(N) bundles having to be involved comes from.

Comment: @ACuriousMind. Well it comes from this: Monopoles are thought to have some topological structure. Therefore it is natural to think that this refers to the topology of the underlying bundle. However, if all bundles are trivial, I don't see how a monopole can have a topology.

Comment: But as I said in my first comment, the "monopole" refers to something charged under a U(1) (or more generally some $\mathrm{U}(1)^k$ or whatever), i.e. an *Abelian* group. What bearing does the (non-)existence of non-trivial bundles for the non-Abelian SU(N) have on this? The monopole can be topologically non-trivial as a U(1) configuration even if the SU(N) configuration it comes from is trivial, can it not?

Comment: @ACuriousMind. Well, the full gauge group is SU(N), so whatever winding the monopole has in the U(1) can be unwound in the larger SU(N). If not it wouldn't be the case that SU(N) is trivial. Unless you mean to say that SU(N) is broken down to U(1), but that doesn't happen in pure gauge theory (and pure gauge theory is still said to have monopoles according to the 't Hooft construction cited above).

Comment: @ACuriousMind. I'm starting to think it has to do with the fact that one must use the gauge group $SU(N)/\mathbb Z_N$ instead of $SU(N)$, and with this new gauge group, there are non-trivial bundles.